# What does this double pointer do in c programming?

Tags: c, pointer-to-pointer

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 3

char *words[LENGTH];

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
     char *pc;    // a pointer to a character
     char **ppc;  // a pointer to a pointer character

     printf( "\n------------Multiple indirection example\n" );


 // initialize our array string

   words[0] = "zero";
   words[1] = "one";
   words[2] = "two";

// print each element
   for ( int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i )
   {
      printf( "%s \n", words[i] );
   }


   ppc = words; // initialize the pointer to pointer to a character


   for( int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)   // loop over each string
   {
       ppc = words + i;
       pc = *ppc;
           while (*pc != 0) {                   // process each character in a string
            printf("%c ", *pc);             // print out each character of the string individually
            pc += 1;
            }
        printf("\n");

   }




return 0;
}
```

The part that says " char **ppc  " declares a char double pointer. Then it says ppc = word . What is the difference between a regular pointer variable being assigned to words and this double pointer variable? I also don't get why a regular pointer variable would be assigned to have the value of a double pointer variable. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Nitpick: a double pointer usually means a pointer to a `double` type variable. The term you want here is a pointer to pointer.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use a global variable here. In fact, it complicates what could be `char *words[] = { "zero", "one", "two", NULL }` where `LENGTH` is no longer necessary either.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you need to learn:

1. All arrays naturally *decay* to pointers to their first element. So for example as an expression `word` is really the same as `&word[0]`. Since `word` is an array of `char *` elements, a pointer to such an element must then be `char **`.
2. For any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* the same as `*(p + i)`. From this follows that `p[0]` is the same as `*(p + 0)` which is the same as `*p`.

If we now put it all together we start with

```
ppc = words;
```

which according to point 1 above must the same as

```
ppc = &words[0];
```

It makes `ppc` point to the first element of the array `words`.

Then we have

```
ppc = words + i;
```

which will then be equal to

```
ppc = &words[i];
```

I.e. it makes `ppc` point to the i:th element in the array `words`.

Finally we have

```
pc = *ppc;
```

which is the same as

```
pc = ppc[0];
```

But since `ppc` points to the i:th element of the array `words`, the last assignment is really the same as

```
pc = words[i];
```

The variable `ppc` isn't really needed in this program, other than as an example.

---

To illustrate it, lets "draw" it out...

We have the `words` array:

```
+---+     +--------+
| 0 | --> | "zero" |
+---+     +--------+
| 1 | --> | "one"  |
+---+     +--------+
| 2 | --> | "two"  |
+---+     +--------+
```

In the first iteration of the loop, when `i == 0`, then we have

```
ppc = &words[0];
```

which leads to

```
+-----+     +---+     +--------+
| ppc | --> | 0 | --> | "zero" |
+-----+     +---+     +--------+
            | 1 | --> | "one"  |
            +---+     +--------+
            | 2 | --> | "two"  |
            +---+     +--------+
```

Then we have the second iteration, when `i == 1` which then give

```
ppc = &words[1];
```

which looks like

```
            +---+     +--------+
            | 0 | --> | "zero" |
+-----+     +---+     +--------+
| ppc | --> | 1 | --> | "one"  |
+-----+     +---+     +--------+
            | 2 | --> | "two"  |
            +---+     +--------+
```

And exactly the same for the third and last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted an array of `char*` (array of words) you will need a `char** pointer`

so for example: `char** wordsArr = {"hello","word"}` is an array of `char*`, and you can treat each cell as a string.

it is different from `char* words = "hello world"`
because if we wanted to print just the first word, `printf("%s",words)` will print `"hello world"`
where `printf("%s",wordsArr[0])` will print `"hello"`